# In CentOS 4.3 Webmin 1.3000 bandwidth monitoring is eating disk space. How to delete those files?

Tags: linux, centos, squid

I maintain Linux server being used for Mail, Squid and DNS service. Recently I observed that something was eating server disk space. But at last, today I caught the culprit which was consuming the disk by storing large number of files.

On this server, Webmin 1.300 is installed. We use Squid proxy and Sarg to monitor Internet access. I always manually clear Sarg generated files under /var/www/html/squid for last few years.

But I never realized that Webmin is also storing some kind of bandwidth log files in its' directory structure. I have noticed that under /etc/webmin/bandwidth/hours it has stored more thousands of files since year 2007 totaling about 17 GB. We have used 40 GB HDD for this server machine.

My question is how can I delete those (/etc/webmin/bandwidth/hours) files safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm` is your friend. You apparently don't use that feature so it doesn't matter if removing offending files breaks that bandwidth monitoring.

On a side note: webmin 1.3000 was released in 2006 and CentOS 4.3 (also from 2006) indicates a severe lack of patching as well, you may want to consider upgrading...

Comment: Since it is live server I wanted to confirm it. So just simple delete `rm` will do the job?
And yes, I will be upgrading hardware as well as OS now. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting the oldest files, shouldn't have any impact, except to free up space. Deleting the most current one might see that re-created , but that doesn't matter.

Comment: OK, I will delete all files except most recent one. Thank you very much!